# What are the rules of "on me" in sentences like "You fell asleep on me?"

Tags: prepositions, idioms

There are some phrases I have heard, such as

*"Don't sleep on him"* meaning don't disregard/neglect him

- **EX:** Billy might have been the best kickball player last week, but don't sleep on Jimmy. (gives the feeling that Jimmy might be better than Billy, but you have to watch to find out.)

"You fell asleep on me"* implying I expected something from someone (such as to meet up, receive a call, etc) but they slept instead of following through.

- **EX:**  You said you were going to meet me for coffee but instead you fell asleep on me.

Please describe how "on me" works here and what the rules are.

Comment: Different idioms may have different meaning. Are you trying to find rules to cover them all?

Comment: I don't know the first one. _Fall asleep on me_ and _walk out on me_ have the sense 'while in my presence' (you were expecting companionship but the person went to sleep/went away). _Tell on me_ is a different idiom.

Comment: @WXJ96163 If there are different rules, then yes that would be nice.

Comment: @KateBunting I have edited my post with examples, and removed "told on me"

Comment: I would only expect _fell asleep on me_  if the sleeper was actually in the company of someone who had been hoping for conversation, lovemaking or whatever from them.